# Ranking in SSRS 2008

Tags: ranking

I have a report in SSRS grouped by Property Name and I would like to rank the bookings and revenue columns across all the Properties. If anyone could give some advice on how to do this, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could add two attributes to the *SELECT clause* in your **dataset**

```
SELECT ... 
, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY PropertyName ORDER BY SUM(Bookings) DESC) AS BookingRank
, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY PropertyName ORDER BY SUM(Revenue) DESC) AS RevenueRank
...
```

**RANK** omits a number in case of ties, e.g. 1,2,2,4,5
**DENSE_RANK** would instead give you 1,2,2,3,4 instead for ties on row 2 and 3..